# Swedish characters and login forms PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I've had a look through several posts here and on forums - however I can't figure this out, I have database table with user info and the username has some swedish characters - Ä

I've followed through a few guides but can't seem to make this work any way, my mysql table is set to utf-8 swedish, row looks like the following

```
(`username`, `password`) VALUES('ELDMÄSTARE', '0acf4539a14b3aa27deeb4cbdf6e989f')
```

However when I run simple PHP login form

```
<?PHP
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include("config.php");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $uname = mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper($_POST['username']));
    $pword = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '{$uname}' AND `password` = '{$pword}'";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($result) {
        if ($num_rows > 0) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
            header ("Location: panel.php");
        } else {
            $errorMessage = "Error logging on";
        }
    }
}
head();

?>

<P><?= $errorMessage;?></P>
<FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST" ACTION="index.php"  accept-charset="utf-8">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td><INPUT TYPE= 'TEXT' Name='username'  value="<?= $_POST['username'];?>" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><INPUT TYPE= 'password' Name='password'  value="" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1"  VALUE = "Login"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</FORM>


</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work... Anyone would have any ideas? The SQL output appears to be fine -

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = 'ELDMÄSTARE' AND `password` = '0acf4539a14b3aa27deeb4cbdf6e989f'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check something like this before the query

```
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');
```