# Get UTF-8 string from MySQL via PHP returned "????????"

Tags: php, mysql

In MySQL I have a string, which is displayed properly in phpmyadmin, with the collation set to `utf8_general_ci` .

In the PHP file, I have set the header using plain HTML:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

The php files are hosted on Ubuntu, Apache 2.2, and the files are saved in `UTF-8 without BOM` (using Notepad++)

I have set the connection to use utf8:

```
@mysql_query("set names 'utf8'", $this->link);
$r = @mysql_query($query, $this->link);
```

it returns the string ( varchar 255 ) and using PHP echo , it is displayed to the browser.

However, I am still getting ????? instead of the actual words.

I can't seem to be able to searched for what I might have missed, your help is much appreciated.

=====  Edit  =====

Database, table and column can have three different collations, I have set them all to utf8_general_ci , and calling mysql_set_charset('utf8') immediately after the connection is made, have solved my problem.

I hope this will act as a useful checklist for future people bumping into the same problem. I for one may very well return in a few months to check if I have missed anything :)

Thanks all for the great input.

Comment: Are you sure that they are *stored* properly?

Comment: Was the data inserted using a UTF-8 pipeline to begin with? Even if the output pipeline is correctly utf8 throughout, the data might have been corrupted before/during database insertion.

Comment: Do you have other text (not from database) correct or in question marks too?

Comment: Check here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994366/swedish-characters-and-login-forms-php-mysql/8994471#8994471

Comment: @tandu I inserted the unicode text in phpmyadmin directly. Will that cause problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure your table is in `utf8_general_ci`.
Database and tables can have a different charset
(can happen when you change it by yourself).

And be careful with some functions, like htmlentities,
which have a default charset parameter set to ISO-8859-1 for PHP <5.4.0
(set to UTF-8 for PHP >5.4.0)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Could be wrong, but I believe PHP 5.3 updated the default charset parameters to UTF-8 for these functions.

Comment: Here is the useful part of PHP doc : `Like htmlspecialchars(), htmlentities() takes an optional third argument encoding which defines encoding used in conversion. If omitted, the default value for this argument is ISO-8859-1 in versions of PHP prior to 5.4.0, and UTF-8 from PHP 5.4.0 onwards. Although this argument is technically optional, you are highly encouraged to specify the correct value for your code.`

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of the fact that the Database, Table, Column can have **3 different collations**. I have set all to utf8_general_ci , plus setting the correct charset as @jeroen suggested, have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think the quotes around `'utf8'` are wrong, but either way, you can just use:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

And suppressing errors with the `@` operator when you are looking for them, is not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Check something like this before the query

```
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');
```

Comment: this is way overkill. set names alone is enough

Answer (score -1):

you can use this to encode the strings to UTF-8 so it will not get ???,  but will change the non urf-8 characters like this /u003. so you can decode it later to present it on a text

```
while($var=mysql_fetch_assoc($r)){
           $e['columnI']=utf8_encode($e['columnI']);
```